# What is wrong with this way of showing the progress of the function?

Tags: python, ipython

Here is my function

```
def f(task_list):
    results = []
    for task_id in task_list:
        results.append(work(task_id))
        print len(results) # show the progress
    return results
```

I use execfile() in ipython to run this function, 
but it seems that the progress is showed 
until the whole function ends

=======================
I tried again, it seems okay now...

Comment: what about when you run it outside ipython?

Comment: Works fine for me (I defined `work()` by `sleep(1)`).  What is stdout connected to for your process?  A terminal or a file?  What's your platform?

Comment: stdout is the terminal, it works fine now. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to force to flush stdout :

```
import sys
def f(task_list):
    results = []
    for task_id in task_list:
        results.append(work(task_id))
        print len(results) # show the progress
        sys.stdout.flush()  # this will force the system to display what is in the stdout queue
    return results
```

Comment: `print` without a trailing comma implicitly flushes stdout.

Answer (score 0):

In python interpreter one can turn off the buffering of the output using `-u` option (this option has different meaning in ipython though).

Just call your script like

```
python -u script.py
```

You can place the option in the `script.py` itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import os
...
```

Hope it will work :-)